# jaxlib.xla_extension.XlaRuntimeError: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Out of memory while trying to allocate 553305856 bytes. BufferAssignment OOM

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, jax

I'm getting this error when running a jax script on multiple GPU.

```
jaxlib.xla_extension.XlaRuntimeError: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Out of memory while trying to allocate 553305856 bytes. BufferAssignment OOM
```

Are there things I can do to solve this?

Comment: There are many github issues related to this: https://github.com/google/jax/issues/788. I had a similar memory issue once and solved it with this command: `os.environ["XLA_PYTHON_CLIENT_PREALLOCATE"] = "false"`. Here are some details about this command https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gpu_memory_allocation.html.

Comment: Yeah so I have tried this and also XLA_PYTHON_CLIENT_MEM_FRACTION=.1, but none of that solved it unfortunately..

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have worked for me.

```
os.environ["XLA_PYTHON_CLIENT_PREALLOCATE"]="false"
os.environ["XLA_PYTHON_CLIENT_MEM_FRACTION"]=".XX"
os.environ["XLA_PYTHON_CLIENT_ALLOCATOR"]="platform"
```

https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gpu_memory_allocation.html

Comment: Some issues with this answer though... First, it seems to be expecting a number like `".50"`, not `".XX"`; I think that was just their generic example. Second, note that for `XLA_PYTHON_CLIENT_PREALLOCATE=false`, it says, "However, this behavior is more prone to GPU memory fragmentation, meaning a JAX program that uses most of the available GPU memory may OOM with preallocation disabled." This seems likely to cause problems when using something like `jax`... And third, the last line looks like it would drastically slow things down, constantly deallocating instead of reusing memory.

Comment: People reading this answer should definitely take a look at that link. One thing it mentions as a possible conflict with `jax` is **TensorFlow**, which by default is also trying to use up GPU resources.